# Render a module template in another one only if it is enabled

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm searching the best way to render a part of a view, depending on the loaded modules when the view is called for rendering. For example, I have a menu bar in which I could have 2,3 or 4 items (4 if all modules are loaded). I'd like to use the Sub/Pub pattern but I think it's not possible to go in that way. I mean, trigger an event from my menu template to my module template in order to display it only if the module is started. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it (don't know if it's the best one).

module1.coffee :

```
@bindTo app, "foo:bar", (callback) -> 
  callback JST['modules/module1/templates/item_template']()
```

menu_template.hamlc :

```
- html = null; app.trigger("foo:bar", (res) -> html = res )
!= html
```